# send email with attachment error

Tags: php

I'm trying to send an email with an csv in attachment but when i use this code not send.

```
$origemPortal = array("Portal Loja - Área Loja","Portal Loja - Área Cliente");    
foreach ($returnData as $row)
        {   
            //$iop=$row["OrigemPortal"];
            $op = $origemPortal[$row['OrigemPortal']];
            //logText($op);
        $final_array = array($row['TicketNumber'],
                             $row['OwnerIdName'],
                             $row['SubjectIdName'],
                             $row['ArvoreAssunto'],
                             $row['cartaoquefezpedido'],
                             $row['CustomerIdName'],
                             $row['CreatedOn'],
                             $op,//without this send email
                             $row['Description']
                            );
        fputcsv($file, $final_array,';');
    }


    logText("<a href=".$fileName.">File created on ".$fileName."</a>");

    fclose($file);

    mail_attachment($name_csv,$fileDir,"email@email.pt","email@email.pt","email","email@email.pt",$name,$name);
```

If I don't put `$op` on `$final_array` send email if i put give do not send.

How can i do to send email with `$op`?

Comment: This is show any error? maybe you should try catch around this code, to see any exception, or get return to mail_attachment to identify any problem

Comment: `mail_attachment` is not a native PHP function